# Porcentagem de Conclusão

Tags: wordpress, porcentagem

Sabem me dizer se é possível fazer igual essa imagem no OptimizeMember (Plugin para área de membros) ? Ou conhecem algum plugin para WordPress que o faça ?? Grato

http://prntscr.com/86wng3

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer isso com jquery, criei um exemplo básico.

**Javascript:**

```
$(function(){
    var total = $('input[type=checkbox]').length;

    $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
        var selecionados = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;

        var porcentagem = (selecionados/total) * 100;

        $('.bar-loaded').animate({
            width: porcentagem+'%'
        });

        $('#box p').html(porcentagem+'%');
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">
    <p>0%</p>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="bar-loaded"></div>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" /> Item 1</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" /> Item 2</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" /> Item 3</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" /> Item 4</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

O exemplo em funcionamento [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/sb6norsj/)